# Systemd stop services inside docker container on stop

Tags: systemd, docker

I have a oneshot service that looks like this

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myservice.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/myservice.sh stop
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The docker image I'm running has

```
STOPSIGNAL SIGRTMIN+3
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/init"]
```

The service is started as expected when I start the container. If I manually run `systemctl stop myservice` it works as expected, but when I run `docker stop mycontainer`, the stop is not called. Is this a stop signal issue or service configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

The service and signal were correct, but `systemd-halt` service must be running for this to work.